# add to variable on radio button click php

Tags: php, jquery, html

i've got the following radio buttons in a form

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Shipping($30)">Express Shipping($30)
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Shipping($15)">Regular Shipping($15)
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Shipping(Free)">Free Shipping
```

and the variables

```
$totalNoShip;
$totalWithShip;
```

The `totalNoShip` variable holds the total before shipping.
I want the variable `totalWithShip` to be updated when one of the radio buttons is clicked.
once this is done I want to print the variable in a span `<span class="finalPrice"> final value here </span>`
how do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTML to

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="30">Express Shipping($30)
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="15">Regular Shipping($15)
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="0">Free Shipping

<input type="hidden" name="total" value="0">
<span class="finalPrice"></span>
```

Then do something with JS like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name="shipping"]').click(function(){

        var $mValue = $(this).val();
        $('.finalPrice').text($mValue);
        $('input[name="total"]').val($mValue);

    });
});
```

Then after you POST, Validate your **total** to see if it is related to the selected **Shipping** type